# Clarification about the ZFC's axiom 0.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's consider the "axiom 0" of ZFC:
$\exists x (x=x)$

I "think to" it as "there exist something which is equal to itself, in other words there exist at least something".

But on the notes where I am studying I find:
"There exists at least a set".

My question is: what is the correct interpretation?
If the latter, why $x$ must be a set and can't be a proper class, for example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proper class is not an object of ZFC. Rather, proper classes are *predicates* of ZFC.

Comment: In ZFC everything is a set. The $x=x$ is just a dummy for any true statement, afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\sf ZFC$ objects of the universe are called sets. Something exists if it is an object of the universe, so if an axiom of set theory says that something exists, we say that there is a set with such and such properties.

(The same it true for other theories, $\sqrt 2$ is a real number since it exists in the real numbers, where as $\sqrt{-1}$ is not a real number for similar considerations. The difference is that we have some "absolute" understanding of what is a real number, but we don't have such understanding regarding sets.)

So what does the axiom tells us? Really just that some set exists. The universe is not empty.

Comment: Does this not also follow from the axiom of infinity?

Comment: Yes. Also from many formulations of first-order logic that require the universe of discourse is non-empty. But repetition is not necessarily a bad thing when writing axioms.

Comment: Presumably, the axiom coud be written $\exists x: true$ ?

Comment: @Yves: Yes, but in a language with just equality and $\in$ you don't have many options... :-)

Comment: Thank you!
I probably misunderstood a crucial point: do the variables in the language of ZFC shift only on sets?
If yes, I think (correct me if I make a mistake, please) that the property "be a set" is implicit on every variable, while the property "be a proper class" simply can't be stated in the language of ZFC.
Yes, there are cases of proper classes, but the statement "let x be a (generic) proper class" can't be expressed in this language. If we would to refer to a proper class A, we have always to declare explicitally what A is (by a formula "$A= \{ x | \varphi (x) \}$.

Comment: @Biagio: Yes, but you *can* say something like "There is no set which is equal exactly to the elements satisfying $\varphi$", in which case you say that $\varphi$ defines a proper class. Then when you say that $x$ is in that proper class, you actually say that $\varphi(x)$ is true.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: perfect! Thank you so much. Solved ;-)